# Link_to doesn't work when using acts-as-taggable-on with custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable

Or rather I don't know how to specify the route for it.

I have my controller setup us:

```
def tags
  @clients = current_user.clients.find_tagged_with(params[:tag])
end
```

and my views

Tags:

```
<% for tag in @client.tags %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, clients_path(:view =>'tag', :tag => tag.name) %>
<% end %>
```

Only problem is that the link (clients_path) goes back to index and not 'all.' I know it has to do with changing the clients_path to somehow tell it to use 'all'. But I don't know how.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your routes using `rake routes`.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'all' but if this is a custom method added to routes, then you should be able to use `all_clients_path` instead of `clients_path`.

Comment: Yes all is a custom method I added, just didn't know how to specify the route. Thanks